# Permanent addition of IP address in route in Linux

Tags: linux, routing

How to permanently add route IP address in linux
For static/temporary adding of IP address in route I am using route add -net "DESTINATION_IP" netmask  gw

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'permanently', I assume you mean across boots. It really depends on the specific distribution of Linux as to how to do this.

Comment: To add permanent static routes to a system, create a file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 (or whichever interface you want to route through).
We can add as many routes as we like by simply incrementing the number at the end of each statement. Once saved a restart of network services will force a read of this route file. 
The syntax of the file should look like this:
ADDRESS0=x.x.x.x
GATEWAY0=x.x.x.x
NETMASK0=x.x.x.x
ADDRESS1=x.x.x.x
GATEWAY1=x.x.x.x
NETMASK1=x.x.x.x


But I do not find any file name like route-eth0 but I have 
ifcfg-eth0
route-bond0
route6-bond0
ifcfg-bond0

Comment: Hey @Aryan it would be better for the OP to put that in your own answer and format it correctly.